# Show $f:\Bbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=2x\cdot |x|+3$ is injective and surjective.

Tags: functions, proof-writing, solution-verification

Show $f:\Bbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=2x\cdot |x|+3$ is injective and surjective.

Here's what I did:

**Injective:** Suppose $f(x_1)$ = $f(x_2)$. If $f$ is injective, then it must follow that $x_1$ = $x_2$.

Case 1) $x_1\ge 0$, $x_2\ge 0$

$f\left(x_1\right)\:=\:2x_1\cdot \left|x_1\right|+3$.

Since $x_1\ge0$ and $x_2\ge0$:

we have $2x_1^2+3$ = $f(x_2)$ = $2x_2^2+3$ = **$x_1$ = $x_2$** as needed.

---

Case 2) $x_1\le0$, $x_2\le0$

$f\left(x_1\right)\:=\:-2x_1\cdot \left|-x_1\right|+3$.

Since $x_1\le0$, $x_2\le0$,

we have $f\left(x_1\right)\:=\:-2x_1\cdot \left|-x_1\right|+3$. = $f(x_2)$ = $-2x_2^2+3$ = $x_1$ = $x_2$ as needed.

---

Case 3) $x_1\ge0$, $x_2\le0$

$f(x_1) = 2x_1\cdot |x_1|+3$

$f(x_2) = -2x_2\cdot |-x_2|+3$

$\rightarrow$ $x_1 \ne x_2$ contradiction

---

Case 3) $x_1\le0$, $x_2\ge0$

$f(x_1) = -2x_1\cdot |-x_1|+3$

$f(x_2) = 2x_2\cdot |x_2|+3$

$\rightarrow$ $x_1 \ne x_2$ contradiction

Since one of the examples cases yields $x_1 = x_2$, we can conclude that $f$ is injective.

**Surjective:** Let $f(x)$ = $y$

We have $y=2x\cdot \left|x\right|+3$

If $x\ge0$, $y = 2x\cdot \:x+3$. Solving for $x$, we get
$x=\sqrt{\frac{y-3}{2}},\:x=-\sqrt{\frac{y-3}{2}}$

If $x\le0$, $y = -2x\cdot \:-x+3$. Solving for $x$, we still get $x=\sqrt{\frac{y-3}{2}},\:x=-\sqrt{\frac{y-3}{2}}$

Thus, we will have a $y$ value for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ hence, $f$ is surjective.

---

> I don't know if this is right, can someone provide some feedback?

Comment: You may want to use the [solution-verification] tag.

Comment: Your injectivity is fine (it could be done faster). Your surjectivity is a bit weird. You should really prove that for all $y$ there exists $x$ such that $f(x)=y$. So in simplest terms, given a y you can find a x. Your last statement seems to do the opposite. The idea is there, two cases you should consider are if the given $y$ is less than or equal to $3$ and the second case is greater than $3$.

Comment: since $x\le0$, $x=\sqrt{\frac{y-3}{2}},\:x=-\sqrt{\frac{y-3}{2}}$, for any given y value we can plug it in and find an x value... is that not right?

Comment: @Yaya123 Strictly speaking that's not right but I do see your idea. I am not sure why you needed to impose $x\leq 0$ at the beginning and also there should only be one possible $x$ and your writting seems to indicate there are two.

Comment: Also I would like to point out the case (3) and (4) of injectivity is not entirely correct, at the end you should say $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$ and thus contradiction.

Comment: @Yaya123 Your surjectivity argument makes it sound like every equation $f(x)=y$ has two (or maybe four) $x$ roots. But you just proved that $f$ is injective, so the solution in $x$ must be unique (if it exists at all). You need to clean up that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor comment:

I notice that when $x \le 0$, for example, in case $2$, $x_1 \le 0$, you wrote

$$f(x_1) = -2x_1\cdot |-x_1|+3=-2x_1^2+3$$

which is techniquely correct.

even though I would evaluate it as follows:

$$f(x_1) = 2x_1|x_1|+3=2x_1(-x_1)+3=-2x_1^2+3$$

There is a mistake in your surjective part as you wrote

> If $x\le 0, y=-2x\cdot -x + 3$

The statement is not true.

You might like to consider $y \ge 3$ and $y<3$ for your surjectivity proof.

---

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 2x^2+3, & x \ge 0\\ -2x^2+3, & x<0 \end{cases}$$

Injectivity: It is alright to verify the $4$ cases as you did.  Also note that $f$ increases on $[0, \infty)$ and increases on $[-\infty, 0]$, hence it is an increasing function on $(-\infty, \infty)$, hence we have injectivity.

Surjective:  We have $f([0, \infty))= [3, \infty)$ and $f((-\infty, 0])=(-\infty, 3]$, hence it is surjective.

Comment: Sorry but why would I consider cases $y\ge3$ and $y<3$? I'm confused about that part

Comment: If $x \ge 0$, $y = 2x^2+3 \ge 3$, if $x < 0$, $y = -2x^2+3<3$.    Also, by considering the cases, we are more careful in what is in the square root. If $y<3$ notice that $y-3 < 0$,  and we shall not write $\sqrt{\frac{y-3}{2}}$ is we are looking for real solution.

Comment: That makes sense, so in the case where $x\ge0$, I have shown a explicit solution for how to find a x value given any real y by the formula $\sqrt{\frac{y-3}{2}}$. How will I do the same for when $x<0$

Comment: If $x \ge 0$, we have $y \ge 3$. If $y \le 3$, we have $x < 0$, $-2x^2+3=y$, hence $x=-\sqrt{\frac{3-y}{2}}$.